# Wordpress CSS style sheet not affecting widget output

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, widget

so I am still quite new to wordpress development so don't rage and I am sorry if I did something really stupid.

So I am having trouble with my CSS, for some reason it's not affecting the widget content output, which can be seen in the movieposterdisplay-class file. What I am trying to do is make the outputted youtube video auto size to fit the container using CSS. What I want to know is why the CSS isn't affecting the HTML code and a solution to fix it.

So far I tried using !important in case the wordpress theme was overriding the CSS but the problem must be related to something else. Thanks in advance for any help.

movieposterdisplayfile

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/includes/movieposterdisplay- 
  scripts.php');

require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/includes/movieposterdisplay- 
  class.php');

function register_movieposterdisplay(){
  register_widget('Movie_Poster_Display_Widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'register_movieposterdisplay');
```

movieposterdisplay-scripts file

```
<?php
function mpd_add_scripts(){

wp_enqueue_style('mpd-main-style', plugins_url().'/movieposterdisplay/css/style.css');

wp_enqueue_script('mpd-main-style', plugins_url().'/movieposterdisplay/js/main.js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mpd_add_scripts');
```

movieposterdisplay-class file (file contains the widget output)

```
<?php
class Movie_Poster_Display_Widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {

parent::__construct(
  'movieposterdisplay_widget', // Base ID
  esc_html__( 'Movie Widget', 'mpd_domain' ), // Name  
  array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'Displays Movie/TV posters, overviews and trailers.', 'mpd_domain' ), ) 
  );
}

public function widget( $args, $instance) {
echo $args['before_widget']; 

  $trailer_key ="http://www.youtube.com/embed/" .$this->display_trailer($instance, $first_movie_result)."?enablejsapi=1";
  ?>

  <div class="youtubeplayer">
    <iframe 
    id="player" type="text/html"
    src="<?php echo $trailer_key;?>"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <?php 
echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

style.css

```
.youtubeplayer {
  position: relative !important;
  padding-bottom: 75% !important; 
  padding-top: 25px !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  border: 5px solid red !important;
}

.youtubeplayer iframe {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: it might be cache

Comment: Tried that it didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: HI Dev john, just a quick 5 cents, don;t have time to work thorugh all. I find best way to ensure that css is using the right selectors to target the html etc, is to edit/add in a browsers web tools -  say firefox's "inspect element".  When you see it affecting the html the way you want, you know you have a usable selector and css.  Reproduce that in your css file.

Comment: Hope this helps? https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/css-stylesheet-not-updating-on-wordpress-website/

Comment: can you provide a link?

Comment: Anamari, Wpza and Tom thanks for the help I appreciate it. I figured it out, I was a complete idiot I had previously renamed the plugin folder when I was working on it so the file path was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an incorrect file path in the movieposterdisplay-scripts file. Whilst the file loaded correctly in the main php file
 `require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/includes/movieposterdisplay- class.php');` 
as it already assigned the correct plugin folder name. It did not enqueue correctly as the code was `wp_enqueue_style('mpd-main-style', plugins_url().'/movieposterdisplay/css/style.css');` and I had previously changed the folder name.

Hence I thought it was loading correctly and running fine, however it was only loading correctly.